# Usage of 'appeal'

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I recently came across the use of the noun **appeal** in a book chapter by Gopnick and Wellman on Theory Theory.  The sentence is:

> Theoretical constructs need not be definitely observable, but they must be appeals to a set of entities removed from, and underlying, the evidential phenomena themselves.

I understand the meaning of the sentence, but I do not know, and could not find in any dictionary a definition of **appeals** which fits there.

Any ideas?

Reference: http://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/2027.42/73444/1/j.1468-0017.1992.tb00202.x.pdf

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikitionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/appeal#English)

> 3: A call upon a person or an authority for proof or decision, in one's favor; reference to another as witness; a call for help or a favor; entreaty.

EDIT:

In this case, you personify the underlying phenomena, making *appeals* synonymous to *draw upon* in this context.

> Theoretical constructs need not be definitely observable, but they must **draw upon** a set of entities removed from, and underlying, the evidential phenomena themselves.

Comment: Thanks, this is the same answer as Grace below, so please see my comments there.

Answer (score 1):

The Oxford English Dictionary has  "4a. The call to a recognized authority for sanction, or decision in one's favour, or to a witness for corroborative testimony." In your example, theoretical constructs must call upon the recognized authority (or higher power) of the set of entities underlying the evidential phenomena  for corroboration.

Comment: Right, but this suggests the authority has some agency to take some action.  Even in a metaphorical way, I do not see how entities underlying evidential phenomena could have such a property.

Comment: The entities they refer to are things like mass, which although typically unobservable, are the basis of theoretical constructs which can describe evidential phenomena like motion.